# How can I find previous class using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I want to get previous tag value with id but when I click on three then got value & when I click on four and five didn't get.

How can I get it?

This is what I tried:-

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul li').click(function() {
        alert($(this).prev('.two').text());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li class="two">Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Read the documentation for the methods you are using! It clearly says that .prev finds the _immediately preceding_ sibling. It also mentions .prevAll

Comment: Thanks @misorude for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.prev( [selector ] )](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)

> Get the immediately preceding sibling of each element in the set of matched elements.

You can use [`.prevAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/prevall/) and `:first`:

> Get the immediately preceding sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the previous sibling only if it matches that selector.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul li').click(function(){
     alert($(this).prevAll('.two:first').text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li class="two">Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The `prevAll` select all previous `.two` element. If you have multiple `.two` it return unwanted result.

Answer (score 3):

> If a selector is provided, it retrieves the previous sibling only if it matches that selector. [docs](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)

Parameter of [`.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) is condition. Mean if previous element is `.two` select it and if not doesn't.
You need to use [`.siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

```js
$('ul li').click(function(){
  console.log($(this).siblings('.two').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li class="two">Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I want to get previous tag value not next, its also working on click on one